# Retry writes mongodb on java application

Tags: java, database, mongodb

I'm trying to make transactions on a mongodb database from a java (Maven) application, and I keep getting the error:

"This mongoDB does not support retryable writes. Please add retryWrites=false to your connection string".

I have tried adding that option but it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ABRIR CONEXION
    
    // Replace the placeholder with your MongoDB connection string
    String uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/?retryWrites=false";
    
    MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(uri))
            .retryWrites(false)
            .build();
    
    MongoClient cliente = MongoClients.create(settings);
    
    MongoDatabase db = cliente.getDatabase("pruebas");
    
    MongoCollection<Document> coleccionProductos = db.getCollection("productos");
    
    ClientSession sesion = cliente.startSession();
    
    try{
        sesion.startTransaction();
        
        coleccionProductos.updateOne(sesion, eq("nombre", "patata"), set("precio", 3.99));
        
        sesion.commitTransaction();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        sesion.abortTransaction();
        System.out.println("Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        sesion.close();
    }
    
    cliente.close();
    System.out.println("Termina");
    
}
```

I tried adding the option but I keep getting the same error, I also tried using a MongoClientSettings and it didn't work either.

I am expecting to disable retryWrites.

Comment: what server topology?

Comment: rs, sharded, standalone? What server and driver versions?

Comment: I don't know the server topology, it's localhost. I have the java driver 4.11. Mongo is community version version 7.0.3. I'm working on ubuntu 22.

Comment: run: `db.runCommand({ hello : 1 })` in the shell